How to delete Multiple Users in Mediawiki
I want to delete Multiple users from the Mediawiki, Who has never contributed to a page.
Do we have any extensions for that or do we have to use SQL query and delete them from DB?
I have tried searching for an extension but couldn't find one, and I don't want to make changes directly in the DB

To remove users that have never contributed, run php maintenance/removeUnusedAccounts.php --delete.
